# Check if date is holiday [TypeError: an integer is required (got type Holiday)]

Tags: python, pandas, time

I read data from a csv with pandas. After reading the data I convert the date column from string to date format and remove the time. I want to create a new column containing the values 0 and 1 that shows, if a day is a holiday (1) or not (0). For that I converted the time strings to datetime and created a holiday calender:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Easter, Day
from pandas.tseries.holiday import EasterMonday, GoodFriday, Holiday, AbstractHolidayCalendar

# convert strings to date
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
# remove time
data['date'] = data['date'].dt.date

# german holidays
class GermanHolidays(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1),
             Holiday('Good Fridy', GoodFriday),
             Holiday('Easter Monday', EasterMonday),
             Holiday('Ascension of Christ', month=1, day=1, offset=[Easter(), Day(39)]),
             Holiday('Internation Womens Day', month=3, day=8),
             Holiday('First of May', month=5, day=1),
             Holiday('Whit Monday', month=1, day=1, offset=[Easter(), Day(50)]),
             Holiday('Liberation Day', month=5, day=8),
             Holiday('German Unity Day', month=10,day=3),
             Holiday('First Christmas Day', month=12, day=25),
             Holiday('Second Christmas Day', month=12, day=26)]

cal = GermanHolidays()
holidays = cal.holidays(start = data['date'].min(), end = data['date'].max())
```

The problem occurs in the last line (holidays = ...) and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type Holiday)
```

I've seen other posts with the same code that work and I can't figure out, what's the reason for this error.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix those rules:

```
rules = [Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1),
         GoodFriday,
         EasterMonday,
         Holiday('Ascension of Christ', month=1, day=1, offset=[Easter(), Day(39)]),
         Holiday('Internation Womens Day', month=3, day=8),
         Holiday('First of May', month=5, day=1),
         Holiday('Whit Monday', month=1, day=1, offset=[Easter(), Day(50)]),
         Holiday('Liberation Day', month=5, day=8),
         Holiday('German Unity Day', month=10,day=3),
         Holiday('First Christmas Day', month=12, day=25),
         Holiday('Second Christmas Day', month=12, day=26)]
```